# Global.asax singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net, singleton

Please help me decide whether this should be good or bad idea to declare a Singleton variable in Global.asax file. (It is not actually singleton pattern, I just want to make sure that only one instance is created for this class.)

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private HTML5Video dailyHtml5Video;

    public HTML5Video DailyHtml5Video
    {
        get
        {
            if (dailyHtml5Video==null)
            {
                dailyHtml5Video = new HTML5Video();
            }

            return dailyHtml5Video;
        }
    }

}
```

Will this cause any thread-related issues or other possible issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not thread safe. You can use Lazy type to create a variable of HTML5Video in a thread safe manner.

```
Lazy<HTML5Video> dailyHtml5Video = new Lazy<HTML5Video>(() => new HTML5Video());
public HTML5Video DailyHtml5Video
{
    get {return dailyHtml5Video.Value;}
}
```

You can read about different versions of Singleton pattern here http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx